# How disable CORS in SoapUI Server Mock?

Tags: cors, soapui

I did a simple GET method for a server Soap UI eg: api/version and I got CORS error in chrome when I access by javascript into my application. How I solve this problem?

Error into console:

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:7777/api/application/version' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions here:

Solution 1-) Disable cors in your browser, if you use Chrome, use this args to start your browser:

```
Crhome.exe disable-web-security — user-data-dir=”<Somewhere in your available disk>\MyCoolTemporaryUserProfile”
```

Solution 2-) Create the CORS configuration into SOAP UI, to this follow this two steps:

2.1-) Create other mock action called CORS with OPTIONS method and put a Header called

```
Access-Control-Allow-Methods
```

And Value

```
GET, POST, OPTIONS, HEAD, PUT, DELETE
```

[image: add CORS]

2.2-) In the Mock Service, edit the OnRequest Script and put this lines:

```
mockRequest.httpResponse.addHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*" )
mockRequest.httpResponse.addHeader( "Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "*" )
```

[image]